# Are there any free applications for audio chatting via Google accounts in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, voip, google-talk

Are there any free applications for audio  chat for Google accounts in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy), it's a multi-protocol instant messaging app that, unlike Pidgin, does support Google Talk voice chat.

It's available in the Ubuntu repositories. You'll also need to install a backend for empathy in order to use gtalk. Install both with:

```
sudo apt-get install empathy telepathy-gabble
```

Comment: Lol that seems a lot easier ;-)

Comment: Empathy will be the standard IM app in ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: I don't know why, it has as many features as a door. Only advantage is its multi-protocol support.

Answer (score 3):

[There are some alternatives:](http://www.google.com/talk/otherclients.html)

- Google Talk --- NO
- Google talk gadget --- YES
- Adium  --- NO
- Pidgin  --- YES
- iChat  --- NO
- Kopete  --- YES
- Miranda  --- NO
- Psi  --- Yes
- Trillian Pro  --- NO

[Though here's someone reporting they got it working on Suse](http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2006/01/google-talk-voice-chat-on-suse.html)

> **Google Talk voice chat on SuSE**
>
> One of the things that I sometimes
>   miss on Linux is the ability of voice
>   chat. Skype is the only IM network
>   that supports voice call to and from
>   Linux machines. However, with recent
>   release of libjingle by Google, it is
>   now possible to call my friends using
>   Google Talk from Linux. psi-jingle
>   branch of psi has implemented the
>   support of libjingle. I recently
>   installed it on my desktop running
>   SuSE 9.3 and it works great. Here is
>   the procedure for installation.
>
> 1. Get the sources either directly from the darcs repository
>
> darcs get --partial
>   --set-scripts-executable http://dev.psi-im.org/darcs/psi-jingle
>
> 2. Install all required packages (use apt)
>
> apt install speex-devel apt install
>   qca-devel
>
> 3. Compile ORTP from source because the version of package in repository
>      was not compatible.
>
> wget
>   http://www.linphone.org/ortp/sources/ortp-0.7.1.tar.gz
>   tar zxvf ortp-0.7.1.tar.gz; cd
>   ortp-0.7.1 ./configure --prefix=/usr/
>   make && make install
>
> 4. Install psi-jingle cd psi-jingle ./configure --enable-jingle
>      --with-qca-inc=/usr/lib/qt3/include/ --with-qca-lib=/usr/lib/qt3/lib/
>             --with-ortp-lib=/usr/lib/ --with-ortp-inc=/usr/include/
>             --with-glib-inc=/opt/gnome/include/glib-2.0/ --with-glib-lib=/opt/gnome/lib/ 
>             --with-glibconfig-inc=/opt/gnome/lib/glib-2.0/include/
>      make
> 5. Fire up psi and login to Google Talk network and start voice chatting.
>
> It is important to note that
>   psi-jingle is an under development
>   code and there may be bugs (although
>   it works fine for me). If there are
>   problems, check artsd is not running
>   and mic is functioning fine.
>
> Note: these instructions will work
>   only with 32-bit OS. While I was able
>   to successfully compile it on amd64,
>   the procedure was non-trivial and
>   required me to edit many Makefiles and
>   source files manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.6 Pidgin has audio and video support for gtalk. It's not in the ubuntu repos yet, but there should be debs somewhere.